# Built-functions for queries add more parameters?

Tags: php, oop

**Hello I have method let's say that checks if row exists:**

```
    /**
    * Method rowExists
    *
    * Checks if row exists with given parameters.
    *
    * @param name The name of the value in a column.
    * @param column The name of the given column.
    * @param table The name of the given table.
    **/

    private function rowExists($name, $column, $table)
    {
        $this->user = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$column." = :name");
        $this->user->execute(array(":name" => $name));

        if ($this->user->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**With this I can check if row exists**

*Usage:*

```
if ($this->rowExistsAnd($this->get['user_id'], $generatedCode, 'user_id', 'generated_code', 'account_verifications') === true) {
```

**Now what I am asking for, this method only supports 1 parameter for checking**

*What if I want to check WHERE two columns?*

**Example:**

*Current query it does:*

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = value1
```

*I want:*

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = value1 AND column2 = value2
```

**I want to do so with 1 method, without creating another method with adding parameters.
*How can I do this?***

Edit:

```
    private function rowDoesExist($params)
    {
        if (count($params) < 4)
        {
            $this->user = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$params[0]." WHERE ".$params[1]." = :name");
            $execute = array(":name" => $params[2]);                
        }
        else
        {
            $this->user = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$params[0]." WHERE ".$params[1]." = :name AND ".$params[2]." = :name2");
            $execute = array(":name" => $params[3], ":name2" => $params[4]);
        }
        $this->user->execute($execute));        
    }
```

Usage:

```
    $this->rowDoesExist(array('users', 'user_name', $username);
```

Comment: You could use arrays instead of single strings. One containing the names of the columns and the other - the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend rewriting your function like this (not tested):

```
private function countRows($table, array $criteria = null)
{
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM $table";
    if ($criteria) {
        $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', array_map(function($column) {
            return "$column = ?";
        }, array_keys($criteria));
    }
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query)
        or die('Failed to prepare query ' . $query);
    $stmt->execute(array_values($criteria));
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
```

First, it's kinda useless to `SELECT *`, if what you want is the rowcount only.

Second, it makes more sense to take filter criterias (for `WHERE` clause) as an associative array: keys will correspond to column names, and values, well, to their expected values. If you want to make more specific function that will always work with a single criteria only, go on:

```
private function countRowsBySingleCriteria($table, $column, $value)
{
  return $this->countRows($table, array($column => $value));
}
```

For me that makes more sense that checking for arguments' type within `countRows`.

Comment: The problem is that this kind of functions' usage quickly grows out of control usually. What if you eventually would like to use it with 3 criterias? Four? Five? It makes little sense using numeric arrays for this purpose when an associative array feels like a natural fit.

Comment: Oh I see. And how do I use that function?

Comment: `$this->countRows('my_table', array('my_column' => 'my_value'))`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You may use array as additon parametr, or using `func_num_args()`, `func_get_arg()` and `func_get_args()` functuins for getting function extra params

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 informations to consider:

- column names (such as `user_id`, `generated_code`)
- operators (such as `=`)
- values to compare with (such as `$this->get['user_id']` and `$generatedCode`

I think you should use an array to achieve this.

```
private function rowExists($table, array $wheres = array())
{
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$table} WHERE 1 = 1";
    $params = array();

    foreach ($wheres as $where)
    {
      $query .= " AND {$where[0]} {$where[1]} ? "
      $params[] = $where[2];
    }

    $this->user = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    $this->user->execute($params);

    if ($this->user->fetchcolumn() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
if ($this->rowExistsAnd('account_verifications', array(
   array('user_id', '=', $this->get['user_id']),
   array('generated_code', '=', $generatedCode)
)) === true) {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
 private function rowExists($name1,$name1, $column1,$column2 $table)
  {
    $cond=" where 1=1";
    if($column1)  
    $cond.=" and ". $column1."=:name1";
     if($column2) 
     $cond.=" and ". $column2."=:name2"
   $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table.$cond;
    $this->user = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    $this->user->execute(array(":name1" => $name1,":name2" => $name2));

    if ($this->user->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I want to do so with 1 method, without creating another method with adding parameters"

Comment: What if I want to only use ONE parameter? Logic.